# display data in grid from database in php [html]

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

This is the template of the grid but its not a static database so i dont know whether a loop will work and if it will i dont know how to use it

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row-fluid">
  <ul class="thumbnails">
    <li class="span3">
    <div class="thumbnail" style="padding: 0">
      <div style="padding:4px">
        <img alt="300x200" style="width: 100%" src="http://placehold.it/200x150">
      </div>
      <div class="caption">
        <h2>Fadahunsi Simeon</h2>
        <p>My project description</p>
        <p><i class="icon icon-map-marker"></i> Place, Country</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer" style="text-align: left">
        <div class="progress" style="background: #ddd">
          <div class="bar bar-danger" style="width: 30%;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="span4"><b>60%</b><br/><small>FUNDED</small></div>
          <div class="span4"><b>$1000</b><br/><small>PLEDGED</small></div>
          <div class="span4"><b>NOT FUNDED</b><br/><small></small></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[so lets say that i select all plumbers from the database how will i show each in the grid with their details(link for how the db looks like)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ssynz.png)

[Link for the grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3eZ5.png)

Comment: Your question in unclear... Can you share your PHP code? I see only html...

Comment: Are you asking how to display your database information inside a table on your website? If so, what have you done so far with your PHP code? Have you connected to your database? Please elaborate and include the code that is missing.

Comment: i dont know what to write in php that can do that.I can connect the database

Comment: Have you managed to fetch data from the database in your PHP script?
If you have then you should use json_encode to convert the data to a format readable by JavaScript and echo it. The you can make an AJAX request to your PHP script and place the results on your grid

Comment: ok i think that will help from your explanation but how do i do all what you have said

Comment: For a start, include your PHP code to your original post

Comment: @dimlucas he does have no PHP code: `i dont know what to write in php that can do that.I can connect the database – Simeon Adedayo 46 mins `

Comment: @Peurr Oh, I assumed that by 'connecting to the database' he meant getting the data with mysqli or PDO.

Comment: @SimeonAdedayo I suggest you first take a look on how to use PHP incombination with MySQLi or PDO before asking these questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a loop in your php to create those containers so as to display the details.

Sample code:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)
while($row){
    echo $row['name']. " - ". $row['age'];
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Loop this way and create those containers.

Sample MYSQL & PHP connection code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['formSubmit'])){
        $DB_USER="root";
        $DB_PASS="";
        $DB_HOST="localhost";
        $DB_NAME="contacts";

        $conn = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        } 

        $name = $_POST['formName'];
        $title = $_POST['formTitle'];
        $enquiry = $_POST['formEnquiry'];

        $sql = "INSERT INTO enquiries (Name, Title, enquiry) VALUES('".$name."', '".$title."', '".$enquiry."')";

        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        if($result){
            alert("Thank You");
        }else{
            alert("error!");
        }
        mysqli_close($conn);


}
?>
```

Comment: @Simeon Adedayo Use the above two snippets & you will be able to display your data.

Comment: @SimeonAdedayo Upvote & select answer if you got your solution.